# Concept of roWebScreen in Roku

Tags: html, webview, video-streaming, roku, brightscript

Is there any concept of roWebScreen in Roku.I just want to have a videoEnabledwebview in Roku just like android.

But roWebScreen doesn't exist in ROKU SDK documentation.Is it there or it has other name in ROKU.

In ROKU forum it is mentioned that somwhere they seen it in 2.8 SDK Documentation.But the post is in 2010.After that they have no updates.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no roWebScreen component in Roku. You can use roScreen with roVideoPlayer for your purpose.

Comment: Ok.Thanks.I will look into it.

Answer (score -1):

There are a bunch of sample code examples available on [Roku SDK webpage](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/The+Roku+Channel+Developer+Program) for different components, the one you are looking for is `customvideoplayer`

Comment: How does the `customvideoplayer` demonstrates implementation of a web view?